# How to change Tabs Layout and Tab style in react bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have added a Tabs layout to show different information. It works well except for the style.

I do not like the style they are using. It's almost what I need some parts needs to be updated.

[image]

and I would like to have a layout like the one below:

[image]

```
 <div className="profile-tabs">
                    <Tabs defaultActiveKey="yourclasses" id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
                        <Tab eventKey="yourclasses" title="Your Classes" tabClassName="profile-tabitem"> 
                            <div className="profile-tab-space">
                            <EmptyTile text={TextContents.CreateYourOwnClass} url="/createaclass"/>
                            </div>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="joinedclasses" title="Joined Classes" tabClassName="profile-tabitem">
                        <div className="profile-tab-space">
                            <EmptyTile text={TextContents.DiscoverANewExp} url="/createaclass"/>
                        </div>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="bookmarks" title="Bookmarks" tabClassName="profile-tabitem">
                        <div className="profile-tab-space">
                            <p> {TextContents.NoBookMarkYet} </p>
                        </div>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey="yourhosting" title="Your Hosting" tabClassName="profile-tabitem">
                        <div className="profile-tab-space">
                            <EmptyTile text={TextContents.HaveBusinessOrHome} url="/createahost"/>
                        </div>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>
                </div>
```

and the css

```
.profile-tab-space {
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;

}


.profile-tabs {
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}




.profile-tabitem {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.77;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #d9d9d9;
}

.profile-tabitem:active {
    font-family: Source Sans Pro;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-stretch: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 0.77;
    letter-spacing: -0.6px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #ff7255;
}
```

AQny idea how to properly style the tabs and tab

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have tried in inspect of the react-bootstrap documentation site. you can try the css below. I have added a screenshot as well.

```
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link, .nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
    color: orangered;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: none;
}

.nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: none;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover{
    color: color:gray
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but how do you apply this css to each tab ? I tried used `id` for tabs and `tabClassName` for the `Tab` but this is not working

Comment: have you tried using !important after all the changed css property?  i didn't understand the reason for using id here where you can simply accomplish with the existing classes.